# Get the index in a multidimensional class

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry for the title i will put here an example of what i want to accomplish:

```
namespace mdclass
{
  class pClass
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      tiles<int> tl = new tiles<int>();
      tl[0].X = 0;
    }
  }

  class tiles<T> : List<T>
  {
    public int X
    {
      //get/set the X-coordonate
    }

    public int Y
    {
      //get/set the Y-coordonate
    }

  }
}
```

how can i transfer the `[0]` from the `tl[0]` in the `public int X` and work with it?

Comment: So you've got a `tiles<int[]>`, which is-a `List<int[]>`. So you need two indices to identify one of the `int`s, one indexing into the `List` and one indexing into one of the contained `int[]`s. So what do you actually want getting or setting, say, `X` to do? Will something like `tl[0][0]` do what you want?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan sorry no that wouldn't help. i've repaired the error in the question ( and i've put an explication in @James Walford Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class for x and y coordinates:

```
public sealed class Point {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Use the `Point` class to store the coordinates into the list:

```
public sealed class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var tiles = new List<Point>();
        tiles.Add(new Point { X = 5, Y = 10 });

        tiles[0].X = 15;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just make tl public?

Then `myInt = mypClass.tl[0].X`

Comment: i think you didn`t understand what i want to do... i have a grid made by this list of tiles. In the `public int X` i want to calculate the X-coord (index % 4 - will give me the x-coord of the square in a grid with 4 columns) but i don't know how to transfer the index 0 from the `tl[0]` to the function `X`.

Comment: So the value of the public int X is a function of its index, but you don't know its index?

Comment: If that's right then all your code should probably be in a Grid class. I don't see why you want all your coordinates in a list when a 2 dimensional structure would fit your data better.

Comment: Rough sketch of class heirachy below, if I've understood.

Answer (score 0):

A data heirachy like this might work for you (no time to add actual code, sorry!). Then you could implement appropriate getters and setters.

```
Public class Grid {

List<Row>

}

Public class Row{
List<Point>

}

Public Class Point{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

}
```